# scrollTop value on safari iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have an arrow-down button on a div to show that it is scrollable. This button disappears either when the user scrolls down or clicks on the button which takes it to the bottom of the div. Now, this button should reappear as soon as the user has scrolled back to the top of the div. For implementing this functionality I checked the `scrollTop` value of the div as:

```
if (element.scrollTop === 0) {
    element.style.display= 'block';
} else {
    element.style.display= 'none';
}
```

I have placed this check on `scroll`, `mousewheel` and `touchmove` events and this works absolutely fine on Windows and Mac Chrome and Safari but doesn't work on Safari on iOS. What are the changes required to make it work on Safari on iOS?

Comment: `element.scrollTop <= 0`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Ya tried that, but it seems the scrollTop value doesn't become 0 or less when we scroll to the top the first time. As soon as it is scrolled upwards again the value becomes 0